# jquery unable to remove table elements by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to remove  elements from a table using the class name they were assigned. Neither $(".className").empty(), nor $(".className").remove() have any effect - the rows in the table below that read "No current reviews" stay present for all items.

```
            for (let item of collection) {
            myTable.append($('<tr>').append($('<td class="review" colspan="3">').text("No current reviews.")));
            if (item.reviews != null) {
                $(".review").remove();
              }
            }
```

EDIT: To clarify, I am building a table with data which I'm pulling from Kinvey through an .ajax query. For each of the items in the collection I want to add a new row to "myTable" which will contain potential reviews. Not all items have reviews. In the code above I'm adding a default element reading "No current reviews", and for the items that do have review(s) I want to remove that element, then later add the actual reviews. However, my attempts to remove the newly added element by using the class name have failed.

Comment: _"I have been trying to remove elements from a table using the class name they were assigned. Neither $(".className").empty(), nor $(".className").remove() have any effect"_ Can you include `html` at Question? `<tr>` appended to `myTable` does not appear to have a `className` set?

Comment: Did you try using $('.review').hide(); and $('.review').show();   ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Please show your full work and also elaborate nicely on what you want to achieve

Comment: Apologies, it's my first time posting here. I'm not even sure which one of you I'm replying right now, or if it's displayed as a general comment.

I will edit my question and add some more info.

Comment: @gibberish, thank you very much - **myTable.find('td.review')** is the syntax I've been looking for, but I am extremely new in this so everything I've googled so far has only been confusing me! Just one more thing:

Why does
`myTable.find('td.review').parent().remove();`
work, but
`$(".review").parent().remove();`
doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should give you something to start with:

```js
var myTable = $('table');

$('#add').click(function(){
     // alert( $(this).index() );
      var row = $('<tr>').append( $('<td class="review" colspan="3">').text("No current reviews.") );
      myTable.append(row);
});

$('#rem').click(function(){
  myTable.find('td.review').parent().remove(); //remove the TR, not the TD
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{border:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td>Cell Two</td>
    <td>Cell Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add">Add Em</button>

<button id="rem">Remove Em</button>
```